# How do I return to the 3D array of a netcdf from an extraction with raster::brick?

Tags: r, extract, netcdf

I have a netcdf that I need to recall to certain dimensions. And then, I want to go back to the same characteristics of the original .nc, that is, a 3D array.
The problem is that using raster::brick I am left with an array of time by coordinates, and what I need is an array(long, lat, time).

Here is some of the code.

```
# Coords
extract.lon <- c(-70.575, -70.525, -70.475, -70.425, -70.375, -70.325, -70.275, -70.225, -70.175, -70.125, -70.075, -70.025, -69.975, -69.925, -69.875, -69.825, -69.775, -69.725, -69.675)

extract.lat <- c(-29.775, -29.725, -29.675, -29.625, -29.575, -29.525, -29.475, -29.425, -29.375, -29.325, -29.275, -29.225, -29.175, -29.125, -29.075, -29.025, -28.975, -28.925, -28.875, -28.825, -28.775, -28.725, -28.675, -28.625, -28.575)

grid <- expand.grid(x = extract.lon, y = extract.lat)
spts <- SpatialPoints(grid, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
    
# read netcdf and brick
nc.var <- "pr"
nc.filename <- paste0(path.inputs, "netcdf/CR2MET/CR2MET_", nc.var, "_v2.0_day_1979_2020_005deg.nc")
nc.data <- raster::brick(nc.filename, varname = nc.var)
    
# Extract data by spatial point
nc.extract <- extract(nc.data, spts)
nc.extract.t <- t(nc.extract) # transpose raster object
    
# nc.extract.t is a matrix of time x coords.
# .... 
# return to array
```

Ideas/help to return to 3D(x, y, time) array

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide enough information to give any answer with certainty, but you might try something like this:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(filename)
e <- ext(-70.575, -69.675, -29.775,  -28.575)

x <- crop(r, e)

a <- as.array(x)
```